# Load JSON file in vue.js with Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js

I've created a vue.js with typescript app using `vue-cli` 3 and selecting the typescript option.

Now I'm trying to import a .json file:

```
import * as config from './config.json';
```

But keep getting the compiler error:

```
Version: typescript 
2.7.17:25, tslint 5.9.1 
Cannot find module './config.json'.
```

The `config.json` file is right next to the `.ts` that is trying to load it.

Is there any additional config I need to add to load .json with the vue-cli templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this. One would be to use require() instead of import for non-js files:

```
const config = require('./config.json')
```

You can also create a .d.ts file with a [wildcard module declaration (under "Wildcard module declarations")](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) which will allow you to import JS files. You can put it anywhere, including it the same as you would any .ts file.

```
// json-module.d.ts
declare module '*.json' {
  const data: any
  export default data
}

// since we use a default export, we now import it like this
import config from './config.json'
```

Answer (score 6):

Add "resolveJsonModule": true to your tsconfig.json